# react-calendar onChange do not set calendar to actual date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

how can I get rid of calendar view setting on actual date after clicking day in a month view?

```
   <Calendar
        onActiveStartDateChange={({ activeStartDate, view }) => { 
           this.onChange2(activeStartDate.getTime()); this.autoLoadHandler(this.state.date, this.state.user) }}

          onChange={() => this.nullFn()} 
          view="month"
          onClickDay={() => this.nullFn()}
    />
```

Even if onchange and onclick day are null functions that return null, or if they are commented. calendar always changes view to current month (if clicked any day in any month)

Comment: I have added my code below, which is working for me.. Let me know whether this solves your issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    };
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          value={this.state.date}        
          onClickDay={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

   onChange = (date) => {
     this.setState({ selectedDate: date }); 
     console.log((date));
   }
```